# Perl system() EXE Permissions?

Tags: windows, perl, cmd, atmel, avrdude

I'm kinda new to running Perl on windows, and I'm having some problems with the system command while trying to run `avrdude.exe` to upload a HEX file to a Atmel Microcontroller.  These are the Perl commands I am using to execute the command:

```
$AVR_CMD = "\"".$AVR_DUDE."\"" . " -C" . "\"".$AVR_DUDE_CONF."\""; 
$AVR_CMD .= " -v -v -v -v -patmega2560 -cstk500v2"; 
$AVR_CMD .= " -P\\\\.\\".$PORT;
$AVR_CMD .= " -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:". "\"".$HEX_FILE."\"". ":i";

system($AVR_CMD);
```

Now, I am printing the final command to ensure that it is OK, and it seems to be.  However, there seems to be some sort of permissions problem in the actual execution.  When I copy and paste the printed command into the windows terminal, it results in this:

```
avrdude.exe: Version 5.11, compiled on Sep  2 2011 at 19:38:36
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is BLOCKED FOR SO

         Using Port                    : \\.\COM4
         Using Programmer              : stk500v2
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude.exe: Send: . [1b] . [01] . [00] . [01] . [0e] . [01] . [14]
```

Which is evidently avrdude being run with the correct parameters. However, when I run this command using `system()`, I receive this output:

```
avrdude.exe: Version 5.11, compiled on Sep  2 2011 at 19:38:36
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is BLOCKED FOR SO

         Using Port                    : \\.\COM4
         Using Programmer              : stk500v2
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude.exe: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\COM4": Access is denied.
avrdude.exe done.  Thank you.
```

This leads me to believe that there is some sort of permissions difference between running a command in CMD and running it through `system()`.  If anyone could offer some insight on this or give me any tips to remedy this problem it would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks beforehand.

EDIT: I have written a Perl script that calls avrdude.org after sending a hard reset to the Atmel (based on some code in [this](http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1201441300) thread):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Win32::SerialPort qw( :STAT 0.19 );
use FindBin qw($Bin);

#Do port reset
foreach (@ARGV)
{
    if ($_ =~ /-P\\\\\.\\(.*)/)
    {
        print "Found -P argument - ";
        print ("Resetting DTR on " . $1 . "\n");
        $P1 = new Win32::SerialPort ($1);
        $P1->pulse_dtr_on(1000);    
        last;
    }
}

select(undef, undef, undef, 0.1);
print ("Executing avrdude\n");
system($Bin . "/avrdude.org " . join(" ", @ARGV));
```

However, this still has the same problem. If the Perl `system()` call has the same permissions as running through the command line, then why can I execute the command in the command line, but COM4 access is restricted when I call the same EXE from Perl? :S

Comment: Re "This leads me to believe that there is some sort of permissions difference between running a command in CMD and running it through `system()`.", No, there isn't. Especially since you told Perl to use `cmd`!

Comment: I'm confused as to why I can access COM4 in avrdude using the command line, but not through perl using the same command... If they have the same permission settings it should work no?

Comment: I've already stated the difference is not between Perl and not Perl, and asking me what the difference is between Perl and not Perl isn't productive.

Comment: i.e. Look elsewhere. How was Perl launched? Was the same command actually used? What's the current work directory? etc etc etc

Comment: I'm launching it from the command line with just a `perl upload.pl`

Comment: You do not show the content of the `$AVR_DUDE`, `$AVR_DUDE_CONF`, `$PORT`, and `$HEX_FILE` variable. That could help to find the issue.

Comment: Let's not dismiss the permission issue just yet. I've ran into a similar issue for the first time, where using system("mkdir -p $dir") didn't work, but mkpath $dir created the path just fine.

Comment: Two comments: 1) As `system` accepts a *LIST*, why taking the efforts to join all the arguments together (BTW: there is a `join` function), also doing quoting (there is a `map` function, too)? 2) If you actually use a *LIST*, try to display it immediately before executing it in the Perl debugger (use `perl -d your_program`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) can take either a string argument, like you did, or a list of arguments. In the latter (recommended) case, the shell handles the quoting for you. So, just make a list of the arguments and pass it. Something like this:

```
my @args = ($AVR_DUDE, " -C", $AVR_DUDE_CONF, 
           qw(-v -v -v -v -patmega2560 -cstk500v2), "-P\\.\.$PORT", 
           qw(-b115200 -D -Uflash:w:), $HEX_FILE, ":i");
system(@args);
```

Note that you do not need to put variables outside double quotes. And you can use other quoting methods to avoid having to escape quotes. E.g.:

```
"\""
```

Can be written in any of these forms:

```
'"'
qw(")
q(")
qq(")
q#"#   # etc
```

See [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, please see my edit in the question.

Comment: I think the number of backslashes in `"-P\\.\.$PORT"` is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your issue may be in quoting the arguments of the command-line.

I tried to simulate your environnement as you did not show the content of all your variables:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $AVR_DUDE = 'avrdude.exe';
my $AVR_DUDE_CONF = 'my-conf';
my $PORT = 'COM4';
my $HEX_FILE = 'file.hex';

my $AVR_CMD;
$AVR_CMD = "\"".$AVR_DUDE."\"" . " -C" . "\"".$AVR_DUDE_CONF."\""; 
$AVR_CMD .= " -v -v -v -v -patmega2560 -cstk500v2"; 
$AVR_CMD .= " -P\\\\.\\".$PORT;
$AVR_CMD .= " -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:". "\"".$HEX_FILE."\"". ":i";

print "$AVR_CMD\n";
```

Here is the output:

```
"avrdude.exe" -C"my-conf" -v -v -v -v -patmega2560 -cstk500v2 -P\\.\COM4 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:"file.hex":i
```

Does that command work when you paste it in Cmd?

If not you'll have to fix the quoting. I suspect that `-C"my-conf"` may be wrong. Try `-C "my-conf"` or `"-Cmy-conf"`.